# Mapping from a class to options in service collection

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

I have a console app that can be run from the command line and the user can input some arguments to influence how the app runs. I would somehow like these arguments to be available throughout my application. My first thought was to simply create a class like this and just map the arguments from the command line to this POCO and pass it around:

```
    public class CommandLineOptions
    {
        public bool Argument1 { get; set; }
        public List<int> Argument2 { get; set; }
    }
```

While functional it's not really clean as I have to pass an instance of this class as a parameter into lots of methods all over the place. Then I thought I could maybe use the Options pattern to register it in the dependency container and just inject it in those classes where I need it. However I could not find any documentation on how to register an options class using command line arguments, only how to use configuration from `appsettings.json` and alike. So what I would like is something like this:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            CommandLineOptions commandLineOptions = CommandLineArgumentHandler.MapArguments(args);

            ServiceProvider provider = new ServiceCollection()
               .Configure<CommandLineOptions>(commandLineOptions)
               .BuildServiceProvider();
        }
```

How can I make this line `.Configure<CommandLineOptions>(commandLineOptions)` do what I want, that is register the CommandLineOptions in the dependency container?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#command-line-configuration-provider

Comment: Why do you want to use the options pattern? Why don't you just inject `CommandLineOptions` directly into the constructors of components that require its values? e.g. `MyComponent(CommandLineOptions options)`. You can register `CommandLineOptions` as follows: `services.AddSingleton(commandLineOptions)`. What would be the advantage of injecting `IOptions<CommandLineOptions>` of injecting `CommandLineOptions` directly?

Comment: That is indeed easier @Steven! I did not know you could register an instance of class as a dependency like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following code achieved what I wanted to do:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            CommandLineOptions commandLineOptions = CommandLineArgumentHandler.MapArguments(args);

            ServiceProvider provider = new ServiceCollection()
               .Configure<CommandLineOptions>(c => 
                    c.Argument1 = commandLineOptions.Argument1;
                    c.Argument2 = commandLineOptions.Argument2)
               .BuildServiceProvider();
        }
```

This allows me to inject `IOptions<CommandLineOptions>` and use Argument1 and Argument2 anywhere in my application without adding the arguments to any `appsettings.json` file.

EDIT:
As @Steven pointed out, an easier way to do this would be:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            CommandLineOptions commandLineOptions = CommandLineArgumentHandler.MapArguments(args);

            ServiceProvider provider = new ServiceCollection()
               .AddSingleton(commandLineOptions)
               .BuildServiceProvider();
        }
```